React Native Calendar TimelineList margin works only on the left side
I'm trying to visualize a calendar item with some padding on the left and right side. When I add some Margin Horizontal here:
const customTheme = {
event: {
borderRadius: 15,
overflow: 'hidden',
marginHorizontal:20, 
padding: 5, 
},
};

It's taking into account only the left side and shifting the component out of screen as seen on the screenshot below:

When I set the marginHorizontal to 0, it's visualized properly as seen here:

Can anybody point me to what's wrong here, please?
